# Question about length of curve?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

> The question: Find length of curve defined by $\displaystyle
>  y=2\ln\left[\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2-1\right] $ from $x=4$ to $x=6$

Here is the work I have done, but I seem to keep getting it wrong. Are there any suggestions as to what else I can do or what I am doing wrong?

---

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2 \ln\left[\left(\frac x2\right)^2-1\right]$$
Then I used the substitution $\displaystyle-u = \left(\frac x2\right)^2 - 1$. The answer I got was $2 \frac 1u \frac x2$.
Substituting back in we get $$2 \frac{1}{\frac{x^2}4 - 1} \frac x2 = \frac{4x}{x^2  - 4}$$

Using this arclenght formula I get $$L = \int_4^6 \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{4x}{x^2  - 4}\right)^2}dx = \int_4^6 \sqrt{1 + \frac{16x^2}{(x^2  - 4)^2}}dx = \int_4^6 1 dx + \int_4^6 \frac{4x}{x^2-4}dx = 1.66 $$

But the correct answer is $2.81$

What did I do wrong?

SIDENOTE: Hi I have posed as another user with the same name, but my computer signed me off and I'm not really sure how to get that account back (cannot remember password to that email!)?
If anyone has any suggestions or should I just start this account?
I am also not familiar with how to add the proper notation, if someone can point me out to that. Thank you.

Comment: You can use for formatting http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: this is unreadable. So either write a beter copy or type in latex http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Comment: Trying to edit now... might take a while then. Thanks

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother, but I'm not sure what I did wrong with the MathJax?!?! I do not get along with computers!

Comment: You have to wrap your math commands around the dollar sign :) so write the dollar symbol, then your commands, then again the dollar symbol.

Comment: I latexified it and removed the images. Hopefully I did not alter the meaning of your post. By looking at how I edited you should be able to do so yourself next time! :) I've also posted an answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that $$\sqrt{a + b} \neq \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} $$

You have used this in your post but it is wrong; the square root is **not** a linear operator!

---

For example, $4 = \sqrt{16} = \sqrt{12 + 4} \neq \sqrt{12} + 2$

Also, think of all the theorems that would become meaningless; Pythagora, for example; 
$c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ would become $c = a + b$. But the hypothenuses in a right triangle is not the sum of the other two sides!